# How do you get install alonside Ubuntu option during the installation?

Tags: 11.10, installation, partitioning, disk, disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No option to install alongside Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91290/no-option-to-install-alongside-windows-7)

During the graphical installation I get only two options in the **allocate disk space** page,

i) erase disk and install Ubuntu ii) something else. i just don't get the third option which is iii) install Ubuntu alongside them.

What do I need to do to get them?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall