# Ubuntu 12.10 install wont let me install alongside windows 7

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7

I decided today to try out Ubuntu 12.10, and want to install on my computer alongside Windows 7. I am new to the whole thing and have never even partitioned a hard drive and before I go changing partitions on my drive I want to make sure i am doing things properly.

I am going into install and the option *install alongside windows* is not available and it only gives me the *something else* option for advanced users, and completely erasing my windows OS and installing ubuntu (which I don't want to do). Any suggestions or help with this please?

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328

Comment: This might be caused by [already having four primary partitions in an MS-DOS-type partition table](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91290/no-option-to-install-alongside-windows-7) (credit [to Oyibo for finding this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7653036#7653036)). I think there are other possible causes of this too, though, like if Windows did not shut down properly (or was hibernated instead of shutting down). On the live CD, please open a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and run `sudo fdisk -l`. Then select all the text, copy it to the clipboard, *edit your question*, and paste it in.