# Dual boot problem, Window 7 and ubuntu 12.04 while installing

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 alongside with my windows 7, but while installing ubuntu 12.04, at time of partition i don't see "Install UBUNTU alongside with windows 7" Option, I only see my entire HDD 500GB Please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [No option to install alongside Windows 7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91290/no-option-to-install-alongside-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

If your wish is to install Ubuntu along side Win-7, but don't want to make Dual Boot then try with WUBI (Windows UBuntu Installer). You will find it inside ISO file OR you can download it online too.
it's an executable file, you can directly run inside Windows. For WUBI installation you will need 30GB separate partition, other installation WUBI will do itself only. It will make UBUNTU entry in NTLDR (Antive Boot Loader of Windows which stores info inside "boot.ini" file, you can say it is like grub.cfg file of ubuntu.)
To install as Dual Boot which will insatll GRUB in replace of NTLDR, you must have made a partition, Try option "Something Else" and set your mount point "/"(root) on selected partition  on which you wish to install Ubuntu.